# How do I deal with my game freezing?

Tags: geometry-dash

I am playing Geometry Dash, and always die at one part that freezes very often. I tried to fix the problem by uninstalling the app, but it still does not work for me.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This is not lag: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're playing a mobile game. If there is a part that freezes often, try putting your phone or tablet into "airplane mode". Often times, freezing and lag can happen when an app tries to load an advertisement. If that does not work for you either, please tell me what Operating System you're on, and i'll update my answer as we go

Comment: I'm not sure why you are downvoted. Do you know that the game downloads ads from internet?

Comment: I do. The ads change every so often while connected to the internet, but they don't while offline

Comment: when playing on mobile, my character sometimes blinks into hazards, and this tip really prevented that... btw, do you happen to know any tip for the same problem using something like bluestacks?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to reduce lag...
On online levels, there is usually a low-detail checkbox you can tick off that will remove certain decorations that cause lag while playing. You can also click on the gear icon on the home screen > help > Low Detail Mode. This overall reduces the lag on all levels by getting rid of the particles of portals, the pulsing rings around orbs, etc.